# Trouble installing numpy for mac os 10.5.8

Tags: python, numpy, installation

I have python version 2.7.2 on my mac. When I download the sourceforge version of numPy/sciPy/matplotlib for Python 2.7, I'm taken through a 5-step installation process, which results in an error:

```
"You cannot install numpy 1.6.2 on this volume. numpy requires python.org Python 2.7 to install."
```

Yet, when I check my python version number by typing "python" in terminal, I get:

```
Enthought Python Distribution -- www.enthought.com
Version: 7.1-2 (32-bit)
Python 2.7.2 |EPD 7.1-2 (32-bit)| (default, Jul 27 2011, 13:29:32)
```

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the numpy installer only wants to install on top of the standard distribution of Python, whereas your default interpreter is the Enthought distribution. Simple fix, though: Enthought [already has](http://www.enthought.com/products/epdlibraries.php) numpy/scipy/matplotlib, so I don't think you need to install them at all.

Comment: I've figured out how to import numpy, but for some reason, many of the numpy commands (genfromtxt, numaray, ma etc) aren't working. Thanks anyway.